# About break statement in c programming and termination of a loop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, switch-statement, break

I have a doubt regarding the `break` statement in this program.
Technically the `break` statement terminates the loop it is presented in, but in this program the `break` is inside the `if` statement.
So, here the `break` should only terminate the `if` statement, right? But it is also terminating the `do-while` statement.
Sorry if I asked something wrong. I am new to programming

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count;
    char response;

    for (count = 1; count <= 100; count++)
    {
        printf("count = %d\n", count);
    
        printf("enter y to continue or any other key to quit");
    
        scanf(" %c", &response);
    
        if (response != 'y')
            break;
    }

    printf("thank you!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if` cannot be "terminated". `break` will "terminate" the most inner loop or `switch ... case`

Comment: The `break` teminated the `for` loop, not the `if` code block. Similarly with `while` and `do ...while` and also with a `switch` case, which isn't a loop.

Comment: Can you imagine ANY case where a break that works like you think would be useful? ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (6.8.6.3 The break statement)

> 2 A break statement terminates execution of the smallest enclosing
> switch or iteration statement.

This break statement in this if statement

```
if (response !='y')
    break;
```

terminates execution of the enclosing for statement.

You may imagine its action the following way

```
for (count=1;count<=100;count++){
    //...    
    if (response !='y')
    goto L1;
}
L1:
printf("thankyou!");
```

You may not use the break statement in an if statement if the if statement is not enclosed in an iteration or switch statement.

The break statement is a jump statement that passes the control outside the smallest enclosing switch or iteration statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "break" statement in two state.

1. In the looping
2. In the switch-case
   If you use in the looping. When the break statement works, loop will be end.
   If you use in the switch-case.When the break statement works in the one of the cases, other cases does not work.
   Implicitly,  the loop is over, if block will not run again.